# SwiftUI: contentShape not affecting onHover area

Tags: swiftui

I thought `contentShape()` would affect the hover "area" the same way it affects the clickable area.

The following image is an example where the hover should not be triggered.

[image: Example image]

Full example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var hovering: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            .foregroundColor(hovering ? Color.white : Color.red)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .contentShape(Circle())
            .onHover { hovering in
                self.hovering = hovering
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Click")
            }
            .padding(24)
        
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to clip the hover area like the click area?**

Comment: Seeing this too. Really annoying — had to use a second view for hit-testing

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear background that cancels the hover value on hover. It’s not going to be perfect as mouse tracking in SwiftUI has lag errors.